# What is the AMF format?

Tags: amf

header 8 bytes:

```
unsigned short unk0; // version?
unsigned short size; // data size
unsigned short unk1; // 
unsigned short unk2; //
```

data:

```
AMF3 correct data: 0x0a 0x0b 0x01 ...
```

It's not standart AMF: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format

What is the AMF format?

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide a lot more context than that.

Answer (score 0):

Flex use AMF to remote call, it transport on HTTP, and you can use HTTP monitor tool like Charles or Fiddler(with FiddlerAmfParser) to see more AMF data.